# different time value in chrome and ie 11 using momentjs

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, datetime, internet-explorer-11, internet-explorer-10

When I run `console.log(moment("2015-12-29 04:02:50.000 UTC", 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss').valueOf());` I get `1451341070000` in chrome. But when I console the same thing in IE 11 I get a different value `1451391234000`.How can I fix this? I want to fix it in IE 10 too.

Comment: I get 1451358170000 both in Chrome 47.0.2526.106 and IE 11.0.9600.18015

Comment: @JeremyThille Ok i forgot to mention that I am running chrome in linux and ie in windows. Do you think it is happening because of that?

Comment: It gives me 1451347370000 in IE11, Iron (Chromium) and Firefox. The problem is in your side.

Comment: @Raj Nonetheless, I get 1451341070000 in IE11 in windows.

Answer (score 1):

It's a timezone mismatch, you're not using the UTC part of the input string so the moment date is created in the local timezone. That's why I got totally different results from you and Jeremy Thille. Easy fix, tell moment it's an UTC date:

```js
// replace ' UTC' by 'Z' (GMT/UTC) in the input string
var input = "2015-12-29 04:02:50.000 UTC".replace(' UTC', 'Z');

// add a Z a the end of the format
var date = moment(input, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ssZ');

console.log(date.valueOf());
document.write(date.valueOf());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
```

This should give `1451361770000` in any browser and timezone.

Another way is to use [`moment.utc()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/):

```js
var input = "2015-12-29 04:02:50.000 UTC";
var date =  moment.utc(input, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss');

console.log(date);

console.log(date.valueOf());
document.write(date.valueOf());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
```